# Confusion over AirBNB for Russian Tourist Visa

Tags: visas, russia, tourist-visas

I applied for Russian Tourist Visa to visit St. Petersburg for 4 nights at a consulate in India after doing some research that Airbnb are acceptable for accommodation proof. I obtained the invitation from an agency in Saint Petersburg (Goingsus) and they added Airbnb details in my invitation.

The invitation has accommodation column which says "apartment for rent" along with host address and phone number. I submitted my Airbnb payment confirmation along which states the same address as well.

However, today, the woman at the visa center was skeptical saying this is not a hotel to which I said it's an apartment. My host gave me the address of the apartment but the woman there kept insisting the apartment needs to have a name and she is unsure if the consulate would approve it. She also said I as well as my host may be called for clarification. However, she took my passport and asked me to collect it next week.

Did I do anything wrong here? What should I clarify if they call me and ask me about my accommodation? And how likely is my visa to be approved or denied?

Comment: Even on AirBnb apartments have their names, so, if it was present, you could add that name to your application. The thing here is that the hotels in Russia should register their international guests, and if your apartment not doing that means that they a **technically** not a hotel, which can be suspicious for consulate. However, you have provided all the documents you have, so at that shouldn't really affect your application. You better return to this site with your own answer about your experience

Comment: Sadly, the apartment has no name. I confirmed this with the host. I'll revert once I have a result. Fingers crossed until then.

Comment: Russua is so bureaucratic country in case of visa issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1st UPDATE:**

I got my visa from Chennai consulate in India today. They neither called my host nor me during these 3 days. So, this does imply consulates do accept AirBNB if proof is submitted along.

**2nd UPDATE:**

Just got back from Russia. I was asked to show proof of accommodation at the border control while entering the Russian Federation. He saw that and stamped me in. No further questions asked.